# Find splitting field of $(x^3-x^2-x)(x^4-x^2+1)$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

As written in the title, I have to compute the splitting field of $$(x^3-x^2-x)(x^4-x^2+1)$$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$

I'd like to understand if my attempt is correst, or if I'm missing something. Here's what I did:

---

First of all, let's call $h(x)$ the first factor, and $g(x)$ the other one.

I focus on $h(x)$: the only root is $0$. Therefore, I can write $h(x)=(x-0) \cdot h_2(x)$ where $h_2(x)$ is a poly of degree $2$ with no roots in $\mathbb{F}_3$, hence it's irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3$. Therefore, *the splitting field of $h(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ is $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}=\mathbb{F}_{9}$*

Now I focus on $g(x)$: it can be written eventually only as products of two irreducible quadratic polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_3$, i.e.

$$x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 = (a x^2 + bx+c)(dx^2 + ex + f)$$ (I used that $-1 = 2 \text{mod}3$)

The conditions I get are

\begin{cases}
ad = 1\\
ae+bd=0 \\
af + be + cd = 2 \\
bf + ce =0 \\
cf = 1
\end{cases}

and doing the computations I found $a=d=c=f=1, b=e=0$. Therefore, it can be written as product of two irred. quadratic polynomials. Therefore, we have that the splitting field of $g$  is $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$

Now, in order to find the splitting field of the original polynomial, I note that the splitting fields of the factors are the same, so it is exactly $\mathbb{F}_9$

Comment: One small computational error: $h(x)$ is the product of $x$ with a polynomial of degree *2*, and so its splitting field should be $\mathbb{F}_9$. This may easily affect the final answer, since your (in)divisibility result changes...

Comment: Other small things: in splitting the quartic you may as well take $a=1, d=1$ since you can multiply both polynomials by $-1$ if need be to make that so. Your fourth condition is $bf+cf=0$ but that should be $bf+ce$...

Comment: Also, you can work 'by inspection' in the quartic: $x^4+2x^2+1$ is factorizable over $\mathbb{Z}$, so you can carry that factorization to $\mathbb{F}_3$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thanks for the feedback. I fixed the first point, is it okay now?

Comment: The first point is correct but your arithmetic on the quartic is wrong; it absolutely splits as a product of two (irreducible) quadratics.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes I'm just trying to fix my computations, many thanks

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I just found $a=1,b=0,c=1$ and $d=1,e=0,f=1$. So this implies that $g$ splits as a product of two irr. quadratics. I just edited my post. Is it okay now?

Comment: Isn't it clear at once that $x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 =(x^2+1)^2$?

Comment: @lukk I think the claim in the very last paragraph needs some justification, but elsewise it seems fine.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Both the factors have the same splitting field. Isn't this enough to conclude that it has to be $\mathbb{F}_9$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki both the factors of the poly have the same splt. field, isn't this enough?